# Spring: java.io.NotSerializableException: MapSqlParameterSource

Tags: java, spring, spring-jdbc

I'm trying to insert a simple base with Spring `JdbcTemplate` mapping the query of parameters with `MapSqlParamaterSource` and am taking error as the data below:

```
public void adiciona(Conta conta) {
  String sql = "insert into contas (descricao, paga, valor, tipo) values (:descricao,:paga,:valor,:tipo)";
  MapSqlParameterSource pss = new MapSqlParameterSource();
  pss.addValue("descricao", conta.getDescricao());
  pss.addValue("paga", "true");
  pss.addValue("valor", conta.getValor());
  pss.addValue("tipo", conta.getTipo());
  getJdbcTemplate().update(sql, pss);     
}
```

Error log:

```
mar 22, 2015 12:16:00 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
GRAVE: Servlet.service() for servlet [spring mvc] in context with path [/contas] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.TransientDataAccessResourceException: PreparedStatementCallback; SQL [insert into contas (descricao, paga, valor, tipo) values (:descricao,:paga,:valor,:tipo)]; Invalid argument value: java.io.NotSerializableException; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Invalid argument value: java.io.NotSerializableException] with root cause
java.io.NotSerializableException: org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.MapSqlParameterSource
```

Java Bean:

```
public class Conta implements Serializable {

  private static final long serialVersionUID = 4678852901357132238L;

  private Long id;
  private String descricao;
  private boolean paga;
  private double valor;
  private Calendar dataPagamento;
  private TipoDaConta tipo;

  // getters and settes
```

Someone can tell me how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like:

```
 this.getJdbcTemplate().update(updateStatement, new Object[] {conta.getDescricao(), "true", conta.getValor(), conta.getTipo()});
```

Comment: Thanks, but I want to use MapSqlParameterSource in my queries, can you help me?

Comment: Yes, I understand. There is another way to use the MapSqlParameter in queries for the Spring-Jdbc?

Comment: If you are really interested in using MapSqlParameter then change your jdbc template to named parameter jdbc template defined like `<bean class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterJdbcTemplate" id="namedParameterJdbcTemplate">  
   <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>  
</bean>  
</beans> `

Answer (score 2):

I also faced the same issue, I resolved it by changing it from

```
this.getJdbcTemplate().update(query,mapSqlParameterSource);
```

to

```
this.getNamedParameterJdbcTemplate().update(query,mapSqlParameterSource);
```